# Unable to insert html into jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, backbone.js

I am tying to insert some html into a div on my page but it is not working. I am trying to insert templated html $('#users-found').html(tpl) but it will not work. It works when I use this.$el.append, but I want it to change each time they search for a user. Any ideas?

```
define([
  'jquery',     
  'underscore', 
  'backbone',
  'parse',
  'text!templates/searchUsers_tpl.html',
  'text!templates/userList_tpl.html'    
], function($, _, Backbone, Parse, SearchUsersTpl, UserListTpl){
var SearchUsersView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: '#content',

    initialize: function(){
        console.log('search users');
        this.render();
    },

    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(SearchUsersTpl);
    },

    events: {
        'click #submit-search': 'search'
    },

    search: function(){
        var self = this;
        var input = $('#search-users-input').val();
        console.log('search input: ' + input);
        var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
        query.equalTo('username', input);
        query.find({
            success: function(results){
                console.log("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " users.");

                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    var object = results[i];
                    console.log(object.id + ' - ' + object.get('username'));
                }

                var tpl = _.template(UserListTpl, {users: results});
                $('#users-found').html(tpl);
            },
            error: function(){
                console.log('search for user failed');
            }
        });
    }

}); 
  return SearchUsersView;      
});
```

The html that gets loaded when the view is made, SearchUsersTpl

```
<h1>Find Friends</h1>
<br>
<br>
<input id='search-users-input' type="search" value="" placeholder="search username" class="topcoat-search-input">
<button type='search' id='submit-search' class='topcoat-button'>Search</button>
<br>
<br>
<div id='#users-found'></div>
```

The template

```
<div>
 <% _.each(users, function(user) { %> 
    <li><%= user.get('username') %></li> 
 <% }); %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your DIV has the wrong ID. it should be < div id='users-found' >< /div > not < div id='#users-found' >< /div >

The has h is only used as a selector but not required when specifying it as an ID.

Comment: I don't see how my div has the wrong id.
<div id='#users-found'></div>


$('#users-found')

Comment: Id's do not start with Hashtags, infact an ID with a Hashtag is invalid. Ids are just plain strings. You use # when selecting in CSS or jQuery.

Comment: so use: <div id='users-found'></div> $('#users-found') and it should be valid

Comment: Annnnnnnnd it works now. Thanks guys. Been staring at code for too long tonight :)

Answer (score 1):

make sure the user template is converted into a jQuery object. Try replacing:

```
$('#users-found').html(tpl);
```

with

```
$(tpl).appendTo($('#users-found').empty());
```

Comment: Edited your answer to include `.empty()` and use code formatting

Comment: Just tried it out and it didn't work. I don't understand why my solution doesn't work when this.$el.html(tpl) works in all of my other views.